# Version Compatibility of Application

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store

After uploading the iPhone App to the Appstore, how will the appstore handle the version compatibility of the devices ?
For example "Twitter" app, when clicking on "Install" it pop ups up with message saying "App is compatible in ios5"
How can this be done in my iPhone Application which I'm going to upload in AppStore ?
Will this be done by APPLE or do we need to code from our end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you are using classes from a new SDK version and you are targeting an older versie of the OS you should check at runtime if a class is available.

For example:

```
if (NSClassFromString(@"TWTweetComposeViewController") != nil) {"
     TWTweetComposeViewController *twViewcontroller = ....
} else {
     // Some other twitter library
}
```

This is the save way to check support for a specific class.

Comment: @rckoenes... I'm not using the "TWTweetComposeViewController". I'm using Sharekit for these 2 frameworks. So how this can be done ?

Comment: no.. its not detecting now. I haven't added any code in the launch to check if ios version is 5 or less than 5. And use the FRAMEWORKs... I haven't put any code in my app. So How will I handle this now ??

Comment: The docs on the [ShareKit 2.0](https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit#sharekit-20) state that on iOS 5 the native controle will be used. It looks like your either using sharekit in the wrong way or it has become broken.

Comment: No... It works fine ios 5.0. But only when using lesser version then its having issues.

Comment: That is what I ment by "on iOS 5 the native controle will be used". ShareKit comes with it's own Oauth and connection library ans will use these on iOS 4 on 5 it will use the native Twitter libarry.

Answer (score 2):

It will get set automatically by the value you chose for your deployment target for your app. Check the build settings for your target.

Comment: But I have set deployment target as 4.0 when BUILDING. But since Twitter framework is supported in iOS 5 and FaceBook FRAMEWORK in ios 4.3. How will this be compatible.

Comment: You should have tested your app on a real device running 4.0 if you set this as the target! It will probably just crash right away when those new classes are used.

Comment: Yes.. I have checked in the devices less than ios 5.0.... and it crashes... Is there any way to handle this TWITTER and FACEBOOk frameworks, so that it runs in lower version of IOS... I want to run the same app in ios less than version 5.0. Is this possible ?

Comment: No. You can weaklink some frameworks and dynamically load those classes needed, but then, this functionality is gone.

Comment: Like is there anywhere during the APP Launches, check if its version 5.0 or less than this. And Load the frameworks ? Is there any way like this ??

Comment: Typically you "weaklink" (do a search on that) and use NSClassFromString. It will give you lots of results and a good read.

Comment: Okay thats fine. But now since I have already uploaded my app to AppStore. Can I handle the "INSTALL" link in the appstore. Like users clicking on "INSTALL" in the appstore will get a pop-up saying "App is supported in ios version 5.0". Can I handle this from my end in Appstore ??

Comment: No. You should reject it and never release it (in case the app gets approved at all).